# PHP Regex Functions

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am trying to validate form input data using PHP's preg_match function.  I am a little confused of how to use it.  If I want to validate say an alphanumeric string, I would use ^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$ as the first parameter and the string we're validating as the second one.  But how would I use preg_match to tell if it's valid or not?  Would I do this:

```
if(preg_match("^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$", $_POST['display_name'])){
  "String is valid";
} else {
  "String is not valid";
}
```

Or the other way around?  I am currently using the if not preg_match if statement but it's returning false for some reason...  I know this is probably an easy answer, but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`ctype_alnum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, `ctype_alnum()` does not include spaces.

Comment: @Radu: I wasn't sure whether the space was a typo. The OP stated that they wanted "to validate say an alphanumeric string".

Comment: I think what you need to do first is to pick best answers on those 12 other questions without best answers.

Comment: `it's returning false for some reason...` You would have gotten a helpful warning, if you hadn't turned down `error_reporting()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FALSE return from a preg_match indicates an error

you need to delimit your regex (see the leading and trailing / you can use other characters too

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['display_name'])) {
```

Comment: escape? you mean add a delimiter

Comment: Just some nitpicking: a regex cannot return `false`, only a function like `preg_match` that *uses* a regex can. It also does't necessarily indicate an error, if `preg_match` returns `false` it means there was no match. `preg_match` does *throw an error* if the regex is invalid, but apparently the OP has turned off error reporting. :)

Comment: @deceze i have edited the returns false from regex to returns false from preg_match. according to the manual it says returns false on error, returns 0 for no match. although i have not run tests to verify that the manual is correct.

Comment: Oh, there you go. It slipped my mind that `preg_match` usually returns `0` or `1`. So ignore that point of my picking. :)

Comment: Not quite true... Yes, the PHP documentation for `preg_match()` says that it returns FALSE on error. Unfortunately, PHP versions 5.3.3 and below have a bug ([#52732](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52732)) where `preg_match()` does NOT return `FALSE` on error (it instead returns `int(0)`, which is the same value returned in the case of a non-match). This bug was fixed in PHP version 5.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need add the delimiters of your pattern, like this:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['display_name'])
```